# Breakout trading strategy along with various technical indicators error

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, trading

Breakout Trading Strategy to say whether there has been a breakout and should we invest our money. I am writing a code for the same.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
length = 14
k = 1.0
method = 'Atr'
show = False

# Data
# Replace [...] with your price and volume data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
close = data['close']
high = data['high']
low = data['low']
src = close

# Calculate pivot highs and lows

def find_pivot_highs(data, length):
    pivot_highs = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] > max(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] > max(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_highs.append(i)
    return pivot_highs


def find_pivot_lows(data, length):
    pivot_lows = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] < min(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] < min(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_lows.append(i)
    return pivot_lows

ph = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
pl = find_pivot_lows(low, length)

# Calculate slope
def calculate_slope():
    if method == 'Atr':
        return ta.atr(high, low, close, length) / length * k
    elif method == 'Stdev':
        return ta.STDDEV(src, length) / length * k
    elif method == 'Linreg':
        sma1 = ta.SMA(src * n, length)
        sma2 = ta.SMA(src, length)
        return math.fabs(sma1 - sma2 * ta.SMA(n, length)) / ta.VAR(n, length) / 2 * k


slope = calculate_slope()
slope_ph = [0] * len(close)
slope_pl = [0] * len(close)
slope_ph = [slope[i] if i in ph else slope_ph[i-1] for i in range(len(close))]
slope_pl = [slope[i] if i in pl else slope_pl[i-1] for i in range(len(close))]

upper = [0] * len(close)
lower = [0] * len(close)
upper = [src[i] if i in ph else upper[i-1] - slope_ph[i] for i in range(len(src))]
lower = [src[i] if i in pl else lower[i-1] + slope_pl[i] for i in range(len(src))]

# ----
single_upper = [0] * len(src)
single_lower = [0] * len(src)

for i in range(length, len(close)):
    if close[i] > upper[i-length]:
        single_upper[i] = 1
    elif i in ph:
        single_upper[i] = single_upper[i-1]

    if close[i] < lower[i-length]:
        single_lower[i] = 1
    elif i in pl:
        single_lower[i] = single_lower[i-1]

upper_breakout= [False] * len(src)
for i in range(len(src)):
    if src[i] > upper[i]:
        upper_breakout[i] = True
    else:
        upper_breakout[i] = False

lower_breakout= [False] * len(src)
for i in range(len(src)):
    if src[i] < lower[i]:
        lower_breakout[i] = True
    else:
        lower_breakout[i] = False

# Trading strategy
trades = []
trade_type = None
entry_price = None
stop_loss = None
take_profit = None

for i in range(len(close)):
    if trade_type is None:
        if upper_breakout[i]:
            trade_type = 'Long'
            entry_price = close[i]
            stop_loss = entry_price - 0.02 * entry_price  # Example stop loss calculation
            take_profit = entry_price + 0.03 * entry_price  # Example take profit calculation
        elif lower_breakout[i]:
            trade_type = 'Short'
            entry_price = close[i]
            stop_loss = entry_price + 0.02 * entry_price  # Example stop loss calculation
            take_profit = entry_price - 0.03 * entry_price  # Example take profit calculation
    else:
        if trade_type == 'Long':
            if close[i] <= stop_loss or close[i] >= take_profit:
                trades.append((entry_price, stop_loss, take_profit))
                trade_type = None
                entry_price = None
                stop_loss = None
                take_profit = None
        elif trade_type == 'Short':
            if close[i] >= stop_loss or close[i] <= take_profit:
                trades.append((entry_price, stop_loss, take_profit))
                trade_type = None
                entry_price = None
                stop_loss = None
                take_profit = None

# Calculate metrics
total_trades = len(trades)
positive_trades = sum(1 for t in trades if t[2] > t[0])
win_rate = positive_trades / total_trades if total_trades > 0 else 0

cumulative_returns = sum((t[2] - t[0]) / t[0] for t in trades)
sharpe_ratio = (cumulative_returns - 0.01) / (cumulative_returns.std() + 1e-9)
sortino_ratio = (cumulative_returns - 0.01) / (cumulative_returns[cumulative_returns < 0].std() + 1e-9)
profit_factor = sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] > t[0]) / abs(sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] < t[0]))

# Print metrics
print(f"Total Trades: {total_trades}")
print(f"Positive Trades: {positive_trades}")
print(f"Win Rate: {win_rate * 100}%")
print(f"Cumulative Returns: {cumulative_returns * 100}%")
print(f"Sharpe Ratio: {sharpe_ratio}")
print(f"Sortino Ratio: {sortino_ratio}")
print(f"Profit Factor: {profit_factor}")

# Plotting
plt.plot(close[length:], label='Closing Price')
plt.plot(upper[length:], label='Upper Trendline', color='#26a69a')
plt.plot(lower[length:], label='Lower Trendline', color='#ef5350')

for i in range(len(close)):
    if upper_breakout[i]:
        plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='^', color='r', label='Upper Break')
    if lower_breakout[i]:
        plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='v', color='g', label='Lower Break')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here if the lower_breakout is True, one must short and vice versa for upper_breakout.

While running the code: I'm getting an error saying:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:265: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:223: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  arrmean = um.true_divide(arrmean, div, out=arrmean, casting='unsafe',
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:257: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Beyond/BRAINWorks/Internship/Project #304/strategy (ta-lib).py:141: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  profit_factor = sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] > t[0]) / abs(sum(t[2] - t[0] for t in trades if t[2] < t[0]))
Total Trades: 82
Positive Trades: 82
Win Rate: 100.0%
Cumulative Returns: 246.0%
Sharpe Ratio: 2450000000.0
Sortino Ratio: nan
Profit Factor: inf
/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Beyond/BRAINWorks/Internship/Project #304/strategy (ta-lib).py:153: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The resize_event function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use callbacks.process('resize_event', ResizeEvent(...)) instead.
  plt.plot(close[length:], label='Closing Price')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 391, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: -14 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Beyond/BRAINWorks/Internship/Project #304/strategy (ta-lib).py", line 159, in <module>
    plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='^', color='r', label='Upper Break')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 981, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1089, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 393, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: -14
```

I'm trying to understand if the code has any errors, but I can't find any issues.

I'm very new to python and all your help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(length, len(close)):
if upper_breakout[i]:
    plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='^', color='r', label='Upper Break')
if lower_breakout[i]:
    plt.scatter(i, close[i-length], marker='v', color='g', label='Lower Break')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would be much more useful if you include an explanation of how it solves the problem.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although code-only answers are considered low quality, they are still considered answers (even if they are wrong answers). The appropriate response is to downvote, not to vote to delete (unless it is a new answer to an older question that basically just repeats existing older answers).